# I cannot assign output to value in Verilog

Tags: verilog

I am trying to assign `ADDR` to `pcOut` but `ADDR` is showing up as `xxxxxxxx` in GTKWave.

Here is my code:

```
module processor (
    input CLK,

    // Memory
    input [31:0] DATAOUT, // Memory data out
    output [31:0] DATAIN, // Memory data in
    output [31:0] ADDR, // Memory address
    output WE // Memory write enable
);
    wire [3:0] aluSel;
    wire [4:0] regSel1, regSel2, regDataSel;
    wire regLoad, aluEnable, pcLoad, pcNext;
    wire [31:0] regDataIn, regDataOut1, regDataOut2, aluOut, pcOut, pcIn, aluA, aluB;

    assign ADDR = pcOut;

    controlUnit controlUnit (
        .CLK(CLK), // Clock

        // Outputs
        .memDataOut(DATAOUT),
        .regDataOut1(regDataOut1),
        .regDataOut2(regDataOut2),
        .aluOut(aluOut),
        .pcOut(pcOut),

        // Load and enable
        .pcLoad(pcLoad),
        .regLoad(regLoad),
        .aluEnable(aluEnable),

        .pcNext(pcNext),

        // Selects
        .aluSel(aluSel),
        .regSel1(regSel1),
        .regSel2(regSel2),
        .regDataSel(regDataSel),

        // Inputs
        .pcIn(pcIn),
        .regDataIn(regDataIn),
        .aluA(aluA),
        .aluB(aluB),
        .memDataIn(DATAIN),
        .memAddr(ADDR)
    );

    datapath datapath (
        .pcNext(pcNext),

        // Load and enable
        .pcLoad(pcLoad),
        .regLoad(regLoad),
        .aluEnable(aluEnable),

        // Selects
        .aluSel(aluSel),
        .regSel1(regSel1),
        .regSel2(regSel2),
        .regDataSel(regDataSel),

        // Inputs
        .regDataIn(regDataIn),
        .pcIn(pcIn),
        .aluA(aluA),
        .aluB(aluB),

        // Outputs
        .regDataOut1(regDataOut1),
        .regDataOut2(regDataOut2),
        .aluOut(aluOut),
        .pcOut(pcOut)
    );
endmodule
```

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
`pcOut` is outputting the correct value but `ADDR` is not being set that same value.

Edit 2:
Here is the code for the `controlUnit` module:

```
module controlUnit (
    input CLK,
    input [31:0] memDataOut, regDataOut1, regDataOut2, aluOut, pcOut,
    output reg [0:0] pcLoad, regLoad, aluEnable, pcNext,
    output reg [3:0] aluSel,
    output reg [4:0] regSel1, regSel2, regDataSel,
    output reg [31:0] pcIn, regDataIn, aluA, aluB, memDataIn, memAddr
);
    reg cycle = 0;
    wire [10:0] opcode;
    wire [4:0] rs1, rs2, rd;

    decoder decoder (
        .cycle(cycle),
        .instruction(memDataOut),

        .rs1(rs1),
        .rs2(rs2),
        .rd(rd),
        .opcode(opcode)
    );

    always @(posedge CLK) begin
        case (cycle)
            1'b0: begin
                regLoad <= 0;
                aluEnable <= 0;
                pcNext <= 0;
            end
            1'b1: begin
                pcNext <= 1;
                case (opcode)
                    11'b00000110011: begin // Add
                        regSel1 <= rs1;
                        regSel2 <= rs2;
                        regDataSel <= rd;
                        aluSel <= 0;
                        aluEnable <= 1;
                        regDataIn <= aluOut;
                        regLoad <= 1;
                    end
                    11'b10000110011: begin // Sub
                    end
                endcase
            end
        endcase

        cycle <= !cycle;
    end
endmodule
```

Comment: The ```// Outputs``` comment on the ```controlUnit``` module are inputs to the ```controlUnit``` module. ```pcOut``` is being driven only by the ```datapath``` module. Sorry for the confusion, it's down to my bad commenting.

Comment: the looks like you ADDR itself is driven by multiple sources somewhere in higher levels of hierarchy, not shown here.

Comment: I have had a look and I don't think ```ADDR``` is driven anywhere else.

Comment: Show the code for your `controlUnit` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `controlUnit` doesn't seem to have any logic attached to `memAddr`, but `memAddr` is still an output of `controlUnit`. At the top level, you port map `ADDR` to `.memAddr`, and you also `assign ADDR = pcOut`. You're trying to drive `ADDR` in two different locations.